# Is there any difference advantage in using batchGetItem vs iterating over getItem in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html#BatchOperations : 
These batch APIs are implemented as wrappers around other non-batch DynamoDB operations. BatchGetItem invokes the GetItem for each item in the batch.

And from :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#CapacityUnitCalculations : 
For BatchGetItem, each item in the batch is read separately, so DynamoDB first rounds up the size of each item to the next 4 KB and then calculates the total size. The result is not necessarily the same as the total size of all the items. For example, if BatchGetItem reads a 1.5 KB item and a 6.5 KB item, DynamoDB will calculate the size as 12 KB (4 KB + 8 KB), not 8 KB (1.5 KB + 6.5 KB).

So is there any advantage in terms of response time or anything else by using the batchGetItem api vs iterating over a list and calling the getItem api?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, response time. `BatchGetItem` retrieves items in parallel vs sequential for GetItem. But, there are some other considerations that may be relevant:

1. You need to make sure your table(s) are setup with a decent amount of read units;
2. Check the expected results - you may not get all items in your batch request, so you may need to request again.

Hope this helps.